# Laravel Static Facades and Coupling

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel

I would like someone to explain the concept and usage of static facades in the Laravel 4 framework.

From my understanding it seems to result in tight coupling and hidden dependencies since static class methods are being called. Am I correct?

Comment: Laravel has a community forum, documentation and a lot of resource material available via your favourite search engine.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the docs and didn't quite understand. I'm not really trying to learn Laravel and don't have time to dig through all the info, just trying to understand how it uses dependency injection. I also read this: http://www.nathandavison.com/article/16/using-dependency-injection-and-ioc-in-laravel-4-controllers, which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, thats not quite correct. Static class methods are *not* being called.

What happens is, when you extend Facade, you set the class you want to resolve from the DI container. Facade uses __callStatic to then invoke instance methods on the class resolved from the container.

So, you are not tightly coupled, because you can simply specify a different implementation in the container that your Facade will pick up and use instead.

Also, static class methods are not being called because everything falls through to __callStatic which calls the instance methods of whatever class was resolved from the DI container